# How to return back a list instead of tuple in psycopg2

Tags: python, list, postgresql, numpy, psycopg2

I have the following query

```
    cursor.execute(
    """
    SELECT transform(row_to_json(t)) FROM 
        (select * from table 
         where a = %s 
         and b = %s limit 1000) t;
    """
    , (a_value, b_value))
```

Running `records = cursor.fetchall()` will return a list of size 1 tuples.

Is there anyway to return just a list of lists?

I am asking this because I'd like to transform the list of lists into a numpy matrix, and for looping through to turn the singleton tuples into a list is slow.

Comment: I doubt *very* much that there is any significant slowdown in iterating once over the list of tuples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a quick fix you can return an array:

```
cursor.execute("""
    select array_agg(transform(row_to_json(t)))
    from (
        select * from table 
        where a = %s and b = %s
        limit 1000
    ) t;
""", (a_value, b_value))
```

As Psycopg adapts Postgresql arrays to Python lists then just get that list:

```
records = cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
```

I guess it is possible to subclass `cursor` to return lists in instead of tuples but if you are not dealing with huge sets I think it is not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 38):

When you have more then one rows you can use the following code

```
result = [r[0] for r in cur.fetchall()]
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! 

Comment: Of note to others, without the json conversion, this doesn't turn my results into a list, but just returns the first element.  When using r[0:len(r)], it reverts to being a list of tuples.

Answer (score 2):

you may also use this code

```
result = cur.fetchall()
x = map(list, list(result))
x = sum(x, [])
```